# Comment area will not save text if we input #

Tags: javascript

I have a text area called comments, currently users are giving value which has '#', But doesnt save # when entered in the comments textarea.
HTML:

Comments:

```
<textarea id="COMMENTS" name="COMMENTS" rows="1" cols="50" ></textarea>
```

JS:

```
var comments = $("#addComments #COMMENTS").val();
var URL = setCancel&book="+book+"&comments="+comments;
```

How can I save comments area if we give # along with other text?

Comment: Not passing the data in through the URL would be a start.

Comment: You're missing some quotation marks somewhere...

Comment: I am able to save my text in comment textarea but for instance, If i type 'testing#' it saves only as testing and not testing#, how could i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

URLs are not plain text, some characters (such as `#` and `&`) have special meaning in them. You cannot shove user input into them freely.

If you are going to construct your URLs manually, you need to pass plain text through the `encodeURIComponent()` function first.

A more modern approach would be to use [the URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL).

Comment: I am able to save my text in comment textarea but for instance, If i type 'testing#' it saves only as testing and not testing#, how could i achieve this?

Comment: @shwetha — You do what I said in the answer.